# jQuery: Is it possible to refresh the page when clicking a button in a dialog... and keep the dialog open?

Tags: jquery

I have a web page which opens a jQuery UI dialog which contains a "Save" button.
When clicking on that button, I would like to reload the whole page behind the dialog (as some modified information in the dialog are displayed in the page behind).

Now, I know that the dialog and the page behind are actually the same page... so If I do `window.location.reload();` The whole page is reloaded and the dialog obviously disappears automatically.

I would like the reload to happen behind the dialog (and keep the dialog open), do you think it's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use AJAX on save and reload the content of a DIV only, and not the entire page.

```
//on save..
$.get('page.php', function(data) {
  $('.mydiv').html(data);
});
```

Comment: I first tried something similar, like "$("#main-body").load(location.href+" #main-body>*");"... but I have code in "$(document).ready" that needs to run again... but it doesn't get triggered...

Comment: @Canam you would have to manually run that code. DOMReady only happens once.

Comment: @Canam A `setTimeout` can fix that, though it may be due to the way you are running the code. Keep in mind that `.load` is [asynchronous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony) (Arrg you removed the comment!)

Comment: I was calling the code manually AFTER the .load call... and your comment made me realize I should call this code INSIDE the callback function of the .load call... So far, it seems to work fine! I wanted to avoid using a setTimout.

Comment: I removed that comment a second or two after noticing my mistake... I wanted to do some more tests... but you're sooo fast :)  Thanks a lot for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
window.parent.location.reload();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but this will still make the dialog disappear... it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Use it on `onlick` event of your button and `return false;` after it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with some ajax partially refreshing the rest of the page..

As the dialog itself is part of the html, you need to struct your page in a way that you can refresh just what you need excluding the html of the dialog...